# Quel avenir pour l'expression belge "Mon franc est tombé" ?

Tags: expressions, évolution, belgique

*Mon franc est tombé* signifie que je viens de comprendre quelque chose. Cette expression belge est définie entre autres dans le [Wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/le_franc_est_tomb%C3%A9).

La Belgique étant passée à l'euro, cette expression est parfois changée en *Mon euro est tombé*, bien que cela reste dans un contexte humoristique.

Quel est l'avenir de cette expression ? Doit-on continuer à l'utiliser en dépit de sa désuétude croissante ? Doit-on remplacer le franc par l'euro ? Doit-on l'abandonner complètement ?

Comment: Les français utilisent bien encore le sou dans les expressions (*j'ai pas un sou*) alors que le sou a disparu de la circulation à la révolution française. Je ne connaissais pas *mon franc est tombé*, à rapprocher de l'anglais *the penny has dropped*.

Comment: Vu le nombre de gens qui comptent encore en francs en Belgique, je ne sais pas si il y a lieu de s'inquiéter. (Je ne savais même pas que c'était une expression belge)

Comment: Et bien entendu, pour toutes questions concernant l'euro, prière de s'adresser à un europsychologue.

Comment: Quant à moi, je n'ai plus un kopek !

Answer (score 6):

Je sais que ça n'est pas une grande réponse, mais elle est assez longue pour ne pas être un commentaire :)

En Italie il y a aussi des expressions avec la lire (plus littérales, vraiment) par exemple

> Sono rimasto senza una lira
>
> Je n'ai plus une lire

Et aussi

> Non vali una lira
>
> Tu ne vaux pas une lire (assez offensant)

Pour la première, quand on est passé à l'euro, il était étrange pour certaines personnes de continuer à utiliser le mot *lira* et il semblait plus correct d'utiliser *euro*. Je crois que les deux sont répandues de manière égale maintenant.

Pour la seconde, qui est un peu moins littérale, il semble plus naturel d'encore utiliser  *lira*.

À mon avis, c'est plus naturel d'utiliser *franc*.

Comment: Le deuxième est devenue *de facto* encore plus offensante, maintenant que la lire ne vaut vraiment plus tripette :)

Answer (score 6):

Il existe une pléthore d'expressions en Français qui sont composées de termes qui ne sont plus utilisés couramment, parfois depuis des millénaires.

Quelques exemples:

- *Un bouc émissaire*
- *Un chèque en bois* (temps des gaulois)
- *Plein aux as* (XIXe siècle!)
- *Ca ne mange pas de pain*
- *Toucher le pactole*
- *Pendre la crémaillère*

Donc le franc ou la pièce qui tombe, ça pourrait tenir aussi longtemps.

Comment: Les blagues à 2 ou 5 francs également, se retrouver sans le sou.

Answer (score 5):

La livre (mesure de poids) abolie en 1839 est encore présente sur les marchés français en 2011 :

> — Vous me mettrez pour une *demi-livre* de navets.
>     — Ah, oui, ils ne valent pas *cinq francs six sous* aujourd'hui.

On ne peut pas dire qu'on s'ennuie à *cent sous de l'heure* ici ! On a vraiment plus de *deux sous de jugeote* !

Answer (score 0):

Avant l'euro, quand quelque chose ne coûtait pas cher, on disait qu'il coûtait **trois francs six sous**, soit *trois francs et trente centimes*, à cinq centimes le sou, qui est une ancienne pièce.

L'expression **trois francs six sous** est un peu désuète, mais il m'arrive encore de l'entendre, voire de la prononcer moi-même.

Ce qui est amusant, c'est que **trois francs six sous** (soit 3,30 francs) font à peu près un demi euro (à 6,55957 francs l'euro).